# If $\| y_0^* \|^2 +\| y_1^* \|^2 = 1,$ does there exist $f\in C_0^1(X,E)$ such that $y_0^*(f(x)) + y_1^*(f'(x))>1-\varepsilon?$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, derivatives, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be an open subset and $E$ be a Banach space.

Denote $C_0^1(X,E)$ as the space of $E$-valued functions $f$ on $X$ such that $f,f'$ are continuous, and $f$ vanish at infinity.
Also, denote $\text{supp }f=\overline{\{ x\in\mathbb{R}:f(x)\neq 0 \}}$

> **Question:** Fix two linear functionals $y_0^*$ and $y_1^*$ on $E$ with 
>   $$\| y_0^* \|^2 +\| y_1^* \|^2 = 1.$$ 
>   Given any $\varepsilon>0,\delta>0$ and $x\in X,$ does there exist a function $f\in C_0^1(X,E)$ such that 
>   $$\sup_{z\in X}\sqrt{(\|f(z)\|^2+\|f'(z)\|^2)}=1, $$
>   $$\text{ supp} f \subseteq (x-\delta,x+\delta)$$
>   and
>   $$y_0^*(f(x)) + y_1^*(f'(x))>1-\varepsilon?$$

Let $y^*:=(y_0^*, y_1^*)$ be a function $y^*:E^2_{\ell^2}\to\mathbb{R}.$
By assumption, $\|y^*\|_{\ell^2}=1.$

Choose $y:=(y_0,y_1)\in E^2_{\ell^2}$ with $\|y\|_{\ell^2}=1$ such that 
$$y_0^*(y_0) + y_1^*(y_1)>1-\varepsilon.$$

Now, it remains to construct a function $f\in C_0^1(X,E)$ such that its norm is $1,$ supported in $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ and $f(x)=y_0,f'(x)=y_1.$

However, I have no idea on how to construct such function.

Comment: 1. Why do you need to fix $p$? 2. If you do not bound values of $f$ and $f'$ then it is enough to satisfy $...>0$ as $cf$, $c\to +\infty$, will make the LHS as large as you wish.

Comment: 1. Typo.  2. What is ...?

Comment: I mean if $y_0^*(f(x)) + y_1^*(f'(x))>0$ for some $f$ then one can make the LHS arbitrary large since the values of $f$ are not bounded in $E$ and $y^*$ are linear.

Comment: @A.Γ.: I have added a condition on $f.$ I believe the $f$ in your comment above does not work anymore.

Comment: Yes, it is something I expected. Having in mind Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, isn't it better to add squares like $\sup_{z\in X}(\|f(z)\|^2+\|f'(z)\|^2)=1$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have changed the equation.

Comment: Consider the simple case $E=\mathbb R.$ In particular with $y_0^*=1,$ $y_1^*=0.$

Comment: The support condition implies $$\sup_{z\in X} \lVert f'(z)\rVert_E \geqslant \sup_{z\in X} \frac{\lVert f(z)\rVert_E}{\delta}\,,$$ so for small $\delta$ you cannot reach a large $y_0$ without making the norm of $f$ larger than $1$. Hence you can only have $y_0^{\ast}(f(x)) + y_1^{\ast}(f'(x)) > 1 - \varepsilon$ if $\lVert y_0^{\ast}\rVert$ is small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by Daniel Fischer already gives the answer. A more precise statement is: If you fix $\delta>0$ then such a function exists for any $\epsilon>0$ only if $\|y^*_0\|\leq \sin (\delta)$. In particular, this can only hold for any $\delta>0$ if $y^*_0=0$.

For simplicity of notation assume $x=0$.

The condition: $|f(z)|^2+|f'(z)|^2\leq 1$ implies: $|f'(z)|\leq \sqrt{1-|f(z)|^2}$. Since $f(\pm \delta)=0$ it follows first that $|f(z)|\leq \sin (\delta-|z|)$, $|z|\leq \delta$ and then that
  $$ |y_0^* (f(z)) + y_1^* (f'(z)) | \leq |y_0^*| \sin (\delta-|z|) +
   |y_1^*| \cos(\delta-|z|) $$
When $\|y_0^*\|>\sin(\delta)$ the RHS is uniformly bounded below 1, thus preventing the construction of a solution.

On the other hand, when $y_0^*=0$ you may construct solutions by picking a unit vector $y_1$ with $y_1^*(y_1)=1$ and  a $C^1$ function $\phi:{\Bbb R}\rightarrow [0,1] $ with support in $(-1,1)$ and $\phi'(0)=\sup|\phi'|=1$.
Construct for $0<t<\delta$: 
    $$f_t(z) = y_1 \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} \phi(z/t)$$
One has $\sup(\|f_t\|^2 + \|f'_t\|^2)=1$ and as $t$ goes to zero, $\sup_z\|f_t(z)\|\rightarrow 0$ and $f_t'(0)\rightarrow y_1$. Given $\epsilon>0$ the result follows for $t$ small enough.

Comment: So the norm and support condition cannot co-exist?

Comment: No, the small support and bounded $f'$ implies that $f$, whence $y_0^*(f(x))$  must be uniformly small and then only the term $y_1^*(f'(x))$ is significant.

Comment: What do small support and bounded $f'$ imply on $f?$

Comment: Comes from the mean value theorem: If e.g. $|f'|\leq 1$ then $|f(b)-f(a)|\leq |b-a|$ and since $f$ vanishes on the boundary of the support it is quite small inside.